# Changing session variable after refresh/change page

Tags: php, session, variables

I`ve problem with session variables on my page.

```
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
$_SESSION['test'] = 'test';
```

When i refresh page first time `['test']` is changing to `["test"]=> &string(4) "test"` , after next refreshing page `["test"]=> &array(0) {}`.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `session_write_close();` at the bottom of the page...

Are you using a header() redirect or anything of that nature?  If so, this function ensures that the session variable is written before changing the page.

Comment: no :/ only a href, on local wamp server @ win and apache @ ubuntu everything is ok but when i upload website on my rent server i have this problems :/

Comment: ok , it was registry_globals = on fault :) now everything is working

Comment: @msl, you should post an answer then.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `registry_globals = off` to work right. I had the same problem in a rent server. Now everything is ok

Comment: can you please tell me, where need to change `register_globals = off`  in php.ini it's already 'off'

Comment: did you view `phpinfo()` information?  Try using `ini_set ( 'register_globals' , 'off' ); `